# In List of dicts, find dicts with most values

Tags: python

I have a list of python dicts like this:

```
[{'name': 'A', 'score': 12}, 
{'name': 'B', 'score': 20},
{'name': 'C', 'score': 11},
{'name': 'D', 'score': 20},
{'name': 'E', 'score': 9}]
```

How do I select first three dicts with highest `score` values? `[D, B, A]`

Comment: By "most score values", do you mean "highest score"?

Comment: Sort it by score, slice the result.

Comment: Yes, highest score

Comment: Sort like `mylist.sort(key=lambda x:x["score"],reverse=True)` - and as for the slice, it depends what you mean by "most".

Comment: 1. Sort it by score in descending order then slice the first 3; or
2. Sort it by score in ascending order then slice the last 3

Comment: The above is an in-place sort. If you want to return the sorted copy then use `sorted` instead, and use `key` and `reverse` arguments similarly.

Comment: @RonieMartinez Question implied descending order.

Comment: Question also wants just the `name` elements... `[d['name'] for d in sorted(mylist, key=lambda x:x["score"],reverse=True)[:3]]` should do it (not tested).

Comment: try `.sort(key=lambda x: x['score'], reverse=True)` on the list, this will sort the list by the score

Comment: Well that _almost_ got the OP's example output except that it's a stable sort and they wanted the equal elements in reversed order... So I guess we go with the following version: `[d['name'] for d in list(reversed(sorted(mylist, key=lambda x:x["score"])))[:3]]` Gives `['D', 'B', 'A']`

Answer (score 0):

Sort using the `score` as a key, then take the top 3 elements:

```
>>> sorted([{'name': 'A', 'score': 12},
...     {'name': 'B', 'score': 20},
...     {'name': 'C', 'score': 11},
...     {'name': 'D', 'score': 20},
...     {'name': 'E', 'score': 9}], key=lambda d: d['score'])[-3:]
[{'name': 'A', 'score': 12}, {'name': 'B', 'score': 20}, {'name': 'D', 'score': 20}]
```